# Colour class java

Tags: java, user-interface

The code should basically assign unique colours to numbers between 1 and 45 and every single time that a specific number is drawn, the colour that was assigned to that specific number should be the background of the textfield. The problem is I can't assign a colour to a number.

The code***************************************************************

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lottery extends Frame implements ActionListener{

    private TextField[] t = new TextField[100];
    private Button b;

    public Lottery(){
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
            this.t[i] = new TextField(5);
            t[i].setEditable(false);
        }

        b = new Button("Draw Numbers");
        b.addActionListener(this);

        this.add(b);
        for(int i=0;i<7;i++){
            this.add(t[i]);
        }

        this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowevent){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        this.setTitle("Lottery Draw");
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static int[] lotteryNumbers(){
        int[] numbers = new int[7];
        int i = 0;
        while(i<7){
            int value = 1 + (int)(45*Math.random());
            if(isUnique(numbers,value)){
                numbers[i] = value;
                i++;
            }
        }
        return numbers; 
    }

    public static boolean isUnique(int[] array, int value){
        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        {
            if(array[i] == value) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int[] numbers = lotteryNumbers();
        Arrays.sort(numbers);

        for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
        {
            t[i].setText(Integer.toString(numbers[i]));
        }


    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Start of Application");
        Lottery lot = new Lottery();
        System.out.println("End of Application");
    }

}
```

Comment: It's not clear to me from this code what you're trying to do. Perhaps you need to use a list of class objects, rather than a raw array.

Comment: Where are you setting the background color?

Comment: It is not in there because I cant figure out how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a random color you can do something like this when you set the TextField text:

```
Random r = new Random();
int[] numbers = lotteryNumbers();
Arrays.sort(numbers);

for(int i=0;i<7;i++)
{
    t[i].setText(Integer.toString(numbers[i]));
    t[i].setBackground(new Color(r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat(), r.nextFloat()));
}
```

There is not really a way to come up with a color with one number and keep that same color every time you run the program. Something that could work is creating a static array (size 45 for your different numbers) and hard code color values for each number.

```
private static Color[] colors = new Color[45];
static{
    colors[0] = Color.BLACK;
    colors[1] = Color.BLUE;
    ...
}
```